# Python loop with f strings

Tags: python

I am trying to program a game of blackjack.  At the beginning of a game of blackjack, you have two cards, and you can decide if you would like to be dealt another.  You can keep deciding to have another card as long as your score is below 21.

My deck of cards is a list of 52 dictionaries, each with three values: 'suits', 'ranks', and 'values' like below

```
import random

suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
ranks = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
values = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

deck = []

for suit in suits:
    for rank, value in zip(ranks, values):
        card = {"suit": suit, "rank": rank, "value": value}
        deck.append(card)

random.shuffle(deck)
```

I have created the variable user_cards, which starts out as an empty list, and then gets filled with cards dealt to the user.  Code related to that is:

```
user cards = []

def deal_card():
    """Deals a card"""
    card = deck[rd.randint(0,51)]
    return card
```

There is a while loop that appends a new card to the `user_cards` list (`user_cards.append(deal_card())`) and then tells the user what cards they have and asks if they would like to be dealt another card.  Within the while loop, I have the following:

```
print(f"Your cards are {user_cards}")
```

Instead, I could have a print statement like:

```
print(f"Your first card is the {user_cards[0]['rank']} of {user_cards[0]['suit']}.")
```

My question is, how can I modify my print statement to dynamically update as `'user_cards'` updates?  I think I need to use some kind of for loop but I am not sure how to go about it.

For example, if I have three cards, how can I have it print (either in one or three print statements)?

```
print(f"Your first card is the {user_cards[0]['rank']} of {user_cards[0]['suit']}.")
print(f"Your second card is the {user_cards[1]['rank']} of {user_cards[1]['suit']}.")
print(f"Your third card is the {user_cards[2]['rank']} of {user_cards[2]['suit']}.")
```

Comment: that said, to focus a little more on the question that was asked `range(3)` will return `0`, `1` and `2` in turn. Thus, `for idx in range(3):` will let you refer to `user_cards[idx]` inside that loop.

Comment: All of my print statements are f print statements.  Sorry if I did not word the title properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference to me. I've edited the title.

Comment: Mind, mapping `0`, `1` and `2` to the words "first", "second" and "third" is a part of the problem you've left out :) -- though if the number of cards is bounded enough to let you just write a list, then that can be easy enough (`words = ["first", "second", "third"]` and then `f"Your {words[idx]} card..."`)

Comment: Please [edit] to put a title that describes the actual problem, for example something like *'How can I get the words "first", "second", and "third" in a loop?'* See [ask] for tips on that. On that note, you can probably remove a good chunk of the code since it's not relevant to the problem, like how exactly you're creating `deck` and `user_cards`; instead just show an example of `user_cards` containing three cards.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Is there a library to convert integer to first/second/third](/q/11180845/4518341)

Comment: It's more memory efficient to use `tuples` for sequences that will not be modified. Your `suits`, `ranks` and `values` variables could benefit from this. `ordinals` from @Barmar answer should also be a `tuple`

Comment: @OysterShucker, please only use code formatting for _actual code_, as opposed to technical terms (such as "ordinals" or "tuples"). See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of ordinal numbers, and loop over that while you loop over your cards.

```
user_cards = [{'rank': "2", 'suit': "Spades"}, {'rank': "Jack", 'suit': "Clubs"}]
ordinals = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']

for card, num in zip(user_cards, ordinals):
    print(f"Your {num} card is {card['rank']} of {card['suit']}")
```

Comment: user_cards is not defined in your code ?

Comment: The question says: "I have created the variable user_cards, which starts out as an empty list, and then gets filled with cards dealt to the user."

Comment: yes but if running your code dosn't working because user_cards not defini check ?

Comment: My code just shows what to replace their existing print statements with. I assume their code that fills in `user_cards` is OK.

Comment: I believe that you should provide code that works well and is not defective, with a simple explanation of the code

Comment: I've added something there

Comment: The code has improved significantly, and I want to express my gratitude for your efforts. You are truly a talented programmer, and we greatly benefit from your contributions. Thank you very much, Barmar